# Not sure why my CSS is not being applied to HTML table?

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to find out why my CSS in the external .css is not being applied to my table in my .html file. It is properly linked, as all other css elements show up on the .html, however, for this table, it isn't being applied.

[image: CSS for my table]
[image: Output of table on .html file]

Comment: I think you need "solid" so, "5px solid green"

Answer (score 3):

Please **never** post images of code. Instead, post the code itself, preferably as a runnable Stack Overflow snippet.

You haven't provided a border style.

Try

```css
table, th, td { border: 5px solid green; }
```

[Other border styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style#syntax) you could try:

> dotted - Defines a dotted border.
> dashed - Defines a dashed border.
> solid - Defines a solid border.
> double - Defines a double border.
> groove - Defines a 3D grooved border.
> ridge - Defines a 3D ridged border.
> inset - Defines a 3D inset border.
> outset - Defines a 3D outset border.

Comment: Ohhh thank you very much, I thought "solid" was a part of the color name so I ignored it. Also sorry about that photo thing, first time asking a question on here.